# Generating values for empty attributes

Tags: sparql, optional-variables

I am trying to fill the empty spaces generated by the use of `Optional` in the SPARQL query language. Are there any ways that I can achieve this?

The use of `!bound` on the optional variable generates true or false, but I want to fill the cells with my own values such as "?" or "unknown".

Comment: Please can you show the code you're using currently.

Comment: Select ?a ?b ?c 
Where ?a1 rdfs:type hvs:whi; rdfs:label ?a
?a2 rdfs:type hvs:whi; rdfs:label ?a
Optional
?s1 rdf:type hvs:whi; rdfs:label ?b .
?m hvs:wmm ?a; hvs:into ?s1; hvs:will ?c .
Filer (?c =1 ll ?c = 2 ll (!bound (?c) = 'unknown')

Issue: the resultset has some ?c without values (empty cells). I want to replace these cells with 'unknown'.
Sorry that i cound not follow strickly the syntax of sparql with respect to curves. I am using my phone to type. Regards

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you could use one of the following constructs...

```
COALESCE(?c, "unknown")
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce

or

```
IF(bound(?c), ?c, "unknown")
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-if

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16080026/1281433) by AndyS gives some more examples.

Comment: Thanks so much. I achieved the answer through embedding your option in a subquery.